# How to add shipping and delivery addresses with Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I'm trying to create an E-commerce website with JavaScript, React, and Stripe.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to include a billing and shipping address in my checkout.
I've tried to find an answer online but cant find a working solution I can adapt. Maybe the answer is obvious except to me.

I appreciate any help! I've posted me code below. Thank you.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import "./Payment.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { getBasketTotal } from "./reducer";
import axios from "./axios";
import { db } from "./firebase";

function Payment() {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const history = useHistory();

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getClientSecret = async () => {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`,
      });
      setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
    };

    getClientSecret();
  }, [basket]);

  console.log("THE SECRET IS >>>", clientSecret);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection("orders")
          .doc(paymentIntent.id)
          .set({
            basket: basket,
            amount: paymentIntent.amount,
            created: paymentIntent.created,
          });

        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);

        dispatch({
          type: "EMPTY_BASKET",
        });

        history.replace("/orders");
      });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
  };

  return (
    <div className="payment">
      <div className="payment__container">
        <h1>
          Checkout (<Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>)
        </h1>
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__address">
            <p>{user?.email}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Review Items and Delivery</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__items">
            {basket.map((item) => (
              <CheckoutProduct
                id={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                image={item.image}
                price={item.price}
                rating={item.rating}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="payment__section">
          <div className="payment__title">
            <h3>Payment Method</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="payment__details">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <CardElement onChange={handleChange} />
              <div className="payment__priceContainer">
                <CurrencyFormat
                  renderText={(value) => (
                    <>
                      <h3>Order Total: {value}</h3>
                    </>
                  )}
                  decimalScale={2}
                  value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                  displayType={"text"}
                  thousandSeparator={true}
                  prefix={"$"}
                />
                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                  <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Payment;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe doesn't have an element to collect billing details directly but it's something you can build yourself in your form. Assuming you collect the relevant fields, you would pass the information at the time you call `confirmCardPayment` as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) by passing the `billing_details` parameter:

```
const payload = await stripe
  .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
        address: {
          line1: '1 Main street',
          city: 'San Francisco',
          postal_code: '90210',
          state: 'CA',
          country: 'US',
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Similarly, you can pass the shipping details in the same call in the `shipping` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment#stripe_confirm_card_payment-data-shipping)

```
const payload = await stripe
  .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
    },
    shipping: {
      name: 'Jenny Shipping',
      address: {
        line1: '1 Main street',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        postal_code: '90210',
        state: 'CA',
        country: 'US',
      },
    },
  });
```

You can combine both in one call.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment on my question. I'm not sure I quite understand your advice. I currently have it so the client gives their payment info and it looks like the code you gave but blank spaces for them to fill in. How would I go about building something that collected this information in javaScript?  I've got my heard in a jumble trying to figure this out. I appreciate the help!!

Comment: Ah yes sorry I focused on the Stripe API parameters and left it out to you to do the HTML and JS parts since they work the same as any other form would in your application. Right now you have parts of your form that collect an email for example. I don't really have specific guidance on how to build a basic form and interact with it in JS. Maybe you want to read basic guides like https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-forms-tutorial/ instead?

Comment: Ahh ok. I think I understand your advice better. If I'm understanding you correctly you have given me the code for shipping details and billing. Once collected this information will go to Stripe where I'll be able to see the information?

I just need to build a form to collect the information. Is that a correct understanding?

I appreciate the help. I'm learning a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Stripe allows you collect shipping address for item(s) delivery by adding `shipping_address_collection` when you create a Checkout session.

According to stripe:

> You must also specify which countries to allow shipping to by
> configuring the allowed countries property with an array of two-letter
> ISO country codes. These countries appear in the Country dropdown in
> the Shipping Address form on Checkout.

`const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
//other details
shipping_address_collection: {
allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA'],
},

});`

Check stripe documentation for more detail https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/shipping

Answer (score 1):

if using reactjs, you can require billing address like this

```
        billing_address_collection: 'required'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [shipping_address_collection](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection) as shown below:

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  ...
  shipping_address_collection: {
    allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA'],
  },
  ...
});
```

Also, you can use [payment_intent_data.shipping](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-shipping) to pass a shipping address to **Shipping** section in **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** as shown below. *This doesn't pass a shipping address to **Stripe Checkout** but does pass to **Shipping** section in **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** and you cannot use both `shipping_address_collection` and `payment_intent_data.shipping` at the same time otherwise there is an error:

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  ...
  payment_intent_data: {
    shipping: {
      name: 'John Smith',
      address: {
        country: 'USA',
        state: 'California',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        line1: '58 Middle Point Rd',
        line2: '',
        postal_code: '94124'
      }
    }
  },
  /*
  shipping_address_collection: {
    allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA'],
  },
  */
  ...
});
```

[image]