# Strip API error - Indian regulation law causing payment error in React App

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Developing an eCommerce with Stripe payment gateway, and facing this error every time.

As mentioned in [here](https://stripe.com/docs/india-accept-international-payments#export-of-services) I have to provide the customer's `name`, `billing address`, `description`, and `shipping address`, otherwise, the payment will fail, it's a govt law regulated
in India.

This is the error I am getting in Stripe API logs

```
invalid_request_error - description
As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a description. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports
```

This is the code where I am sending the data to the backend:

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
            // do all the fancy stripe stuff...
            event.preventDefault();
            setProcessing(true);
    
            const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
                }
            }}            
            ).then(({ error, paymentIntent }) => {
                // paymentIntent = payment confirmation

                    db
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(user?.uid)
                      .collection('orders')
                      .doc(paymentIntent.uid)
                      .set({
                          basket: basket,
                          amount: paymentIntent.amount,
                          created: paymentIntent.created,
    
                      })
        
                    setSucceeded(true);
                    setError(null)
                    setProcessing(false)
        
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
                    })
            
                    history.replace('/orders')
            },
            )
        
        }
```

How do I set it up to send the `name`, `billing address`, `description`, and `shipping address` to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

In India, you have to collect relevant information to do transaction exports which Stripe documents here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports

This requires numerous extra bits of details such as a clear charge description but also a shipping and billing details during the PaymentIntent confirmation.

I wrote a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107513/how-to-add-shipping-and-delivery-addresses-with-stripe/69109292#69109292) but at a high level you would collect the address/relevant information yourself and pass the relevant information to `confirmCardPayment()`

Stripe doesn't have an element to collect billing details directly but it's something you can build yourself in your form. Assuming you collect the relevant fields, you would pass the information at the time you call `confirmCardPayment` as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107513/how-to-add-shipping-and-delivery-addresses-with-stripe/69109292#69109292) by passing the `billing_details` parameter:

```
const payload = await stripe
  .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
        address: {
          line1: '1 Main street',
          city: 'San Francisco',
          postal_code: '90210',
          state: 'CA',
          country: 'US',
        },
      },
    },
    shipping: {
      name: 'Jenny Shipping',
      address: {
        line1: '1 Main street',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        postal_code: '90210',
        state: 'CA',
        country: 'US',
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: Thanky you so much.